# How do I update value of a QLabelElement?

Tags: ios, quickdialog

I've initialized a QLabelElement, and then later want to update its value.  However explicitly setting the .value property on the instance of QLabelElement doesn't update its value.  Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to do.  The onSelected delegate is executed when the sayHello button is pressed, but the label element isn't updated:

```
@implementation MyController
{
    QLabelElement *_theLabel;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    QRootElement *root = [[QRootElement alloc] init];
    QSection *section = [[QSection alloc] init];
    _theLabel = [[QLabelElement alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Label" Value:@""];
    QSection *sectionButton = [[QSection alloc] init];
    QButtonElement *sayHello = [[QButtonElement alloc] initWithTitle:@"Say Hello"];

    [sections and controls added to root, etc]

    sayHello.onSelected = ^{
        _theLabel.value = @"Hello has been said"; //<-- this isn't working
    };

    //setting _theLabel.value = @"Hello has been said" here works, but not in the delegate

    self.root = root;

    return self;
}
```

Comment: _theLabel.value = @"Hello has been said";

Comment: Check if your block is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload the cell for that element after it's loaded. Also, be careful with retain loops, use weak variables:

```
__weak QLabelElement *weakLabel = _theLabel;
sayHello.onSelected = ^{
    weakLabel.value = @"Hello has been said"; //<-- this isn't working
   [self.quickDialogTableView reloadCellForElements:weakLabel, nil];
};
```

There's a branch of QD that resolves this automatically, but it's definitely not ready for consumption.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe the onSelected event implementation reloads the data being rendered on the screen. There are a couple ways to approach rendering the update:

1) Reload the entire UITableView

```
- (void)reloadData
```

[Apple Doc - reloadData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)

2) Reload the data if you know the index path

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

[Apple Doc - reloadRowsAtIndexPaths!](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: gotcha, I need to try to find the underlying table view in QuickDialog